# Activity does not show in the recents android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-recents

Scenario - I dont have my application running in the background. I have a receiver implemented for ACTION_USER_PRESENT. In this receiver i start a activity whose manifest settings are :

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivityB"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

This is because there is banner in it for which i credit points to the user  and i dont want the user to be able to launch it again and again for the same banner .

From this activity i launch another activity on some button press. This new Activity MyNewActivity is launched with this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivityB.this, MyNewActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                Intent closeintent = new Intent("MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLOSE");
                closeintent.putExtra("action", "close");
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(closeintent);
                MyActivityB.this.finish();
```

Now my new activity should appear in the recents if I long press home button or the recents button .

But the problem is , when i press home MyNewActivity is not being shown in the recents.

The MyNewActivity is defined in Manifest like this :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyNewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

what am i doing wrong and why not MyNewActivity is appearing in the recents.

Answer (score 3):

As per document [android:excludeFromRecents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)

Task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent apps.

By default, all the activities of an application have the same affinity. Activities with same affinity conceptually belong to the same task. Hence in this case both `MyActivityB` and `MyNewActivity` belong to the same task. `android:excludeFromRecents` ensures the task is not listed in the recent apps.

That is the reason, when `android:excludeFromRecents` is set to true for `MyActivityB`, `MyNewActivity` disappers from history.

**Solution:**

Use `android:taskAffinity` to specify different tasks for both the activities. Use `android:excludeFromRecents` for `MyActivityB` if that task should not be shown in history at all.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivityB"
        android:taskAffinity=".MyActivityB"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyNewActivity"
        android:taskAffinity=".MyNewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: If i give task affinity to both of them then the MyNewActivity is launched and shown in recents but if my app was then in the background with main activity then there are two instances of my app is shown in the recents

Comment: Give same taskaffinity value to all activities(".MainActivity") and for MyActivityB give different value(".MyActivityB")

Comment: Try with removing `android:taskAffinity=".MyNewActivity"` from `MyNewActivity`

Comment: After lot of efforts , what i found is 

        android:excludeFromRecents="true"  
removing this and starting the new activity like this :
    
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
I read somewhere about this that it will remove the current task and makes the new task the start of the new task stack. 

But then the activity B on home press is still shown in the recents .

Answer (score 1):

remove `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from your menifest. because it will remove your app from recents.

Comment: Only removing this is not helping.

Comment: are you facing same problem after removing that line

Comment: Partial answer it is but not complete

Answer (score 0):

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That
>   is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this
>   attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of
>   recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list;
>   set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

From this `android:excludeFromRecents` removes all the activities in the current task. In android all the activities in application have same affinity and belongs to same Task unless you specify.In your case as new activity is starting in same task as your previouse activity and android System is removing new Activity as well from the recent list. So you need to specify `android:taskAffinity` in your manifest for each Activity in manifest and it will fix your issue.

Please refer [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)  for more details.

Fix: Use *android:taskAffinity*

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivityB"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:taskAffinity=".MyActivityB"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyNewActivity"
    android:taskAffinity=".MyNewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: If i give task affinity to both of them then the MyNewActivity is launched and shown in recents but if my app was then in the background with main activity then there are two instances of my app is shown in the recents

Comment: Give same taskaffinity value to all activities and for MyActivityB give different value

Comment: If I dont assign to any other activity and only to MyActivityB then also it means that others have the same affinity (default ).

Comment: yes by default all the activities have same affinity.